upload and overwrite html graph files to wordpress media with python and let them have an own url
If I upload my html graph files to wordpress; the files are saved with an url that contains year/month. I have a folder of Graphs in my wordpressmedia. But I don't succeed in updating the properties and url
# Function to update the media file's metadata to assign it to a specific folder (category)
def update_metadata(media_id, media_folder):
    metadata_url = f"{wp_url}{media_id}"
    new_url = f'{base_url}/app/uploads/{media_folder}/{file_name}'
    data = {
            'title': file_name.replace('_',' ').replace('.html',''),
            'caption': file_name, 
            'alt_text': f"Grafiek van {file_name.replace('_',' ').replace('_Grafiek.html','')}", 
            'source_url': new_url,
            'njt_folders': [filebird_folder_id],
            'featured_media': [filebird_folder_id],
            'link': {
                'rendered': f'{base_url}/app/uploads/{media_folder}/{file_name}',
                'raw': f'{base_url}/app/uploads/{media_folder}/{file_name}'
                }
    }
    
    metadata_response = requests.post(metadata_url, headers=headers, json=data)
   
    if metadata_response.status_code == 200:
        update_response = requests.get(wp_url,headers=headers)
        if update_response.status_code == 200:
            update_metadata = update_response.json()
            print("Media metadata retrieved successfully!")
            print(update_metadata)
        else:
            print(f"Failed to retrieve media metadata: {update_response.status_code}")
            print(update_response.content)

        print(f"File ID {media_id} assigned to category '{media_folder}' successfully!")
    else:
        print(f"Failed to assign the file to '{media_folder}'.")
        print(f'Update md Response: {metadata_response.content}')

I tried several options, but none of the fields where updated.
the mediaurl after uploading a file looks like:
https://www.mywordpresssite.nl/app/uploads/2024/10/waterlevels-s1_Graph.html
but i want it to be static, (no year/date in the url)
https://www.mywordpresssite.nl/app/uploads/graphs/waterlevels-s1_Graph.html

Do I use the right fields?
Is there an easier way to get the same?


the directory app is not the standard name in wordpress. which plugin do you use to manage that ?
